# Greek letters in formulas?

Tags: support, markdown, design

I just encountered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094937/solution-of-an-ode-within-a-finite-interval) which had a formula in LaTeX syntax, like so:

> $$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = F(x, v)\ \ ,\ \ x = A\cos(\omega t + \phi) \ \ ,\ \ v = -A\omega\sin(\omega t + \phi)$$

LaTeX support ["will never be on SO"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow), so I replaced this with the following:

```
dφ/dt = F(x, v),  
x = A*cos(Ωt + φ),
v = -A*Ω*sin(Ωt + φ)
```

I felt that gave a concise and readable formula. But is the use of Greek letters desired/recommended, or should I have spelt them out like `phi`,  `omega` etc, in case people somehow don't have support for Greek characters in their browsers? Or to make the formula less math-like and more code-like, maybe?

Comment: How about `d&phi;/dt = F(x,v),` and `v = -A&Omega;sin(&Omega;t + &phi;)`?

Comment: By the way if that's a pendulum I believe it should be a lowercase ω.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is Stack Overflow we're talking about, I'd go for "make the formula less math-like and more code-like."  The question is tagged [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), so use that if you can.  If not, pseudocode that uses variable names like `phi` and `omega` in place of Greek letters should be fine.

Comment: I considered changing it to proper Matlab code, but shouldn't I respect whatever reason OP had to present the formula mathematically rather than as Matlab code?

Comment: @Junuxx If they had a good reason I'd say yes.  Since the OP chose to leave their formulas in an unsupported format, no you don't have to respect their unspecified reason for doing that.

Comment: I see. Still, I can't really unambiguously translate the formula into matlab code, and an error on the OP's side might actually be the cause of the problem, so I decided to ask them for their code instead. But thanks for the answer, I'll keep it in mind.