# How can I display mathematical formulas on sites that don't support MathJax/LaTeX?

Tags: support, markdown, mathjax, latex, site-specific-formatting

I want to ask a question on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) about the usage of mathematical formulas with WolframAlpha.

[Certain Stack Exchange sites include support for MathJax/LaTex formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/351462), which allows for precise formatting of mathematical formulas. (So for example, on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) the formula `$x^2$` will render as [image: x^2])

Since it seems [universal support for MathJax/LaTeX isn't coming anytime soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30559/351462), I'm looking for an alternative way to render mathematical formulas like `$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$$` on communities which don't have native math rendering.

**How can I display mathematical formulas on Stack Exchange sites that don't support MathJax/LaTeX?**

Comment: You can get help from those LaTeX-rendering sites. You know, the ones that render stuff like an image to insert wherever you want. Other than that, Unicode can help but in a limited and sometimes ugly way.

Comment: _I'm looking for an alternative way to render mathematical formulas on communities which don't have native math rendering._ can you tell me the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @SagarV So I can render mathematical formulas in questions where they are relevant, such as [Does Wolfram|Alpha support Knuth's up-arrow notation?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107802/60818). (Thanks to M.A.R.'s suggestion, I discovered the workaround of rendering LaTex as image using an external site, then embedding the image in my post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thanks to @M.A.R](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298549/how-can-i-display-mathematical-formulas-on-sites-that-dont-support-mathjax-late#comment969511_298549), I was able to find a satisfactory workaround.

Render the equation as a PNG using a LaTeX rendering site like [QuickLaTeX](http://quicklatex.com/) or [TeXRendr](http://www.texrendr.com/). You can then reupload and embed that image on any Stack Exchange site.

[image: sum_(n=1)^∞ 1/2^n = 1]

You can even use simple equations like [image: n=2^k + 1] as part of a sentence using inline images.